# Run-time stack size allocated in dynamic array inside a loop

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

I would like to know how is the run-time stack handled when running the code below

```
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int v[i+1];
        ...
   }
```

Stack is reduced and grown after every loop ? 
Stack is initially allocated by an amount which will fit v[101] ? 
Is it optimized by compiler so it treats v as a pointer and do only heap allocations ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not allowed in C++, so should be tagged only C.

Comment: @EOF `int v[i+1];` is a VLA declaration.

Comment: @EOF I don't know (probably just for the sake of the question). But your comment didn't make sense in regard to the code.

Comment: @EOF The question makes sense to me, I don't know what your issue is, or why you are arguing.

Comment: I just wanted to know how memory is managed in this case. I don't know exactly what it is doing.
Eg. Does every loop the address for v[0] is the same ?

Comment: @edufgf: Not usually. The stack grows *downward* on most common systems, while array addressing grows *upwards*. So, *at best*, the *last* element of the array is always the same. However, alignment requirements can make that change as well. I would not recommend relying on any specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the compiler and optimization settings. A clever compiler could figure out that the biggest size needed is 100, and allocate that once from the stack at the beginning and reuse it. Stack allocation is practically free as it's just a pointer adjustment so it wouldn't make any sense to use the heap instead.